# Netty ctx.executor().scheduleAtFixedRate Task also working when channel is closed

Tags: netty

I using netty version is `4.1.30.Final` , netty server task is what send modbus command request device data schedule (1 minute) .

The client program sometimes repeatedly logs in, and then a channel is not closed. the channel is different before.(it looks the device keep multiple channel). I manual closed prior one 。but period task is woking.

Netty init code

```
  // group is final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutor();

    .addLast(group, serverDataPacketHandler);
```

Check repeat channel.  deviceIdentity is unique send by client program.

```
// loginChannels is Map<String, Channel>

if (loginChannels.containsKey(deviceIdentity) && loginChannels.get(deviceIdentity) !=
            ctx.channel()) {
            // close prev one.
            logger.info("repeatedly login");
            loginChannels.get(deviceIdentity).close();
            loginChannels.put(deviceIdentity, ctx.channel());
        } else {

            loginChannels.put(deviceIdentity, ctx.channel());
        }
```

when device is login

```
Channel channel = ctx.channel();
ctx.executor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {   
               logger.info("task start .......");
               // send modbus command 
               channel.writeAndFlush("01 04 00 00 00 01 crc crc");
           }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Result:

Task is running not 1 minute period. when client repeatedly logs in.

Answer (score 0):

As the `EventExecutor` is shared across different `Channel`s it has notion of closed Channel. If you want to not have it run anymore you will need to call `ScheduledFuture.cancel()`.